# Exponent of $p$-sylow subgroup of symplectic groups over the field $GF(p)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $P$ be the $p$-sylow subgroup of symplectic group $Sp(2n,p)$, where $p$ is an odd prime.

> I want to know if there exists anything about the exponent of $P$?

I know that $Sp(m, p) \leq GL(m, p)$ in general for every even dimension $m$ and $Sp(m,p)$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $GL(\frac{m}{2}, p)$. Information about the structure and exponent of $p$-sylow subgroup of $GL(m, p)$ is available in Huppert's book.  Also, there is an article by A.J. Weir about the $p$-sylow subgroups of classical groups over finite fields with characteristic **prime to $p$** which is not the case that I want. If anyone could help I would thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at this post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116139/exponent-of-sylow-p-subgroup-of-classical-groups-over-a-field-of-characteristi

Comment: @ancientmathematician yes, I also checked the references they mentioned even though  they aren't exact ones, but couldn't find the answer that I want.

Comment: Well perhaps @Nick Gill will see this and answer you.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Hope so, thanks.

Comment: The exponent is the same as for $GL_n(p)$, because the regular unipotent element from $GL$ lies in $Sp$, and this has largest order. Hopefully someone will remember where a reference for that is, because my mind has gone blank right now.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Thank you, yes a reference would be very helpful to me.

Comment: I cannot look right now, but a reference should be in my paper in Journal of Group Theory about groups with a single non-trivial Jordan block for a unipotent element (the regular for $Sp$ is such an element). It's on my website or the arXiv.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven thanks, I'll check that.